# Setting select value with optgroup knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

there is this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gauldivic/wLrhrno9/ which is close to what i want. It has optgroups, but i can't seem to figure out how to set the value

JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers.option = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
       var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
       ko.selectExtensions.writeValue(element, value);   
    }        
};

function Group(label, children) {
    this.label = ko.observable(label);
    this.children = ko.observableArray(children);
}

function Option(label, property) {
    this.label = ko.observable(label);
    this.someOtherProperty = ko.observable(property);
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    this.groups = ko.observableArray([
        new Group("Group 1", [
            new Option("Option 1", "A"),
            new Option("Option 2", "B"),
            new Option("Option 3", "C")
        ]),
        new Group("Group 2", [
            new Option("Option 4", "D"),
            new Option("Option 5", "E"),
            new Option("Option 6", "F")
        ])
    ]);

    this.selectedOption = ko.observable();

    this.specialProperty = ko.computed(function(){
        var selected = this.selectedOption();
        return selected ? selected.someOtherProperty() : 'unknown';
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

HTML

```
<select data-bind="foreach: groups, value: selectedOption">
 <option></option>
<optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: label}, foreach: children">
    <option data-bind="text: label, option: $data"></option>
</optgroup>
```

---

I know this is where one would set the selected option but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. **this.selectedOption = ko.observable();**
Also would this work with multiple selects on the same page?
I will be using this with a database and I want to be able to preselect the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make it work on:  http://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/3m67L5h0/

```
<select data-bind="foreach: groups, value: selectedOption">
     <!--<option data-bind="text:$index()+1"></option>-->
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: label}, foreach: children">
        <option data-bind="text: label, option: value()"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>


<hr />

<div data-bind="text: specialProperty"></div>
```

I had no idea what the   first option was for - you can put it back in if you want by uncommenting it.

Note that the option value has to be with parenthesis as it's observable

Small changes to the viewModel

```
ko.bindingHandlers.option = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
       var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
       ko.selectExtensions.writeValue(element, value);   
    }        
};

function Group(label, children) {
    this.label = ko.observable(label);
    this.children = ko.observableArray(children);
}

function Option(label, property) {
    this.label = ko.observable(label);
    this.value = ko.observable(property);
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    this.groups = ko.observableArray([
        new Group("Group 1", [
            new Option("Option 1", "A"),
            new Option("Option 2", "B"),
            new Option("Option 3", "C")
        ]),
        new Group("Group 2", [
            new Option("Option 4", "D"),
            new Option("Option 5", "E"),
            new Option("Option 6", "F")
        ])
    ]);

    this.selectedOption = ko.observable();

    this.specialProperty = ko.computed(function(){
        var selected = this.selectedOption();
        return selected ? selected : 'unknown';
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I renamed the special other variable to value so you can see where it is set.

Finally, you don't need to call .someOtherProperty() or .value() in your specialProperty as the observable will always be set to the value.

Comment: I just discovered that I put the wrong fiddle up. http://jsfiddle.net/gauldivic/wLrhrno9/2/ is the correct fiddle. That index was myself testing something.I guess my question was in this instance with this.selectedOption = ko.observable();, what would I put there to have the option selected

Comment: The fiddle I put up sets the value and retrieves it. I don't see any differences between the two fiddles that make my answer not work.  I am setting the value of this.selectedOption and retrieving it via this.specialProperty as per both fiddles.  If you need an alert as to when it changes, just use `this.selectionOption.subscribe`

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.

Comment: No worries. As your app grows, those items which don't change (e.g. set once) don't have to be ko.observables.  If you want an example of how to set up knockout with multiple components, have a look at https://github.com/brianlmerritt/knockout-babel-browserify-gulp